# Correct way to use properties

Tags: python, oop

My property getter/setters before

```
class Child(Base):
    @property
    def prop(self) -> Optional[int]:
        """Doc"""
        return getattr(self, "_prop", None)

    @prop.setter
    def prop(self, value: int):
        self._set("prop", value)   # where _set itself is a method to reduce boilerplate
```

Now,

```
prop = Prop.int_prop("prop", "Doc")
```

where `Prop.int_prop` looks like this:

```
@staticmethod
def int_prop(name: str, doc: str) -> property:
    def fget(self: Base) -> Optional[int]:
        return getattr(self, "_" + name, None)
    
    def fset(self: Base, value: int) -> None:
        self._set(name, value)
    
    return property(fget, fset, doc=doc)
```

EDIT: `_set` method

```
# Dump value to event store if event exists
event = self._events.get(name)
if event:
   logger.info(f"Dumping value {value} to {repr(event)}")
   event.dump(value)

# Assign value to local variable
setattr(self, "_" + name, value)
```

On one hand this makes me feel proud, because close to 70% of the project I am working on is the property getters/setters. While I agree the above method is more Pythonic and clean, the method below reduces a lot of code. However, it takes away the ability of VS Code to show docstrings below property names.

Is there a solution to this or a better method in general?

Comment: Is the intention of this code to add type annotations to fields on your class? Can you add `_set` to the question

Comment: @IainShelvington I don't get your question, and `_set` is an implementation detail

Comment: Your property doesn't do anything other than set and get a value, why not just use a regular attribute instead?

Comment: `_set` could probably be replace with simply `setattr(self, "prop", value)`.

Comment: @IainShelvington It's a minimal example. There's no need to show any particular details about *how* the property gets or sets the value.

Comment: But, if 70% of your code consists heavily of getters and setters that *don't* do anything significant, then you should drop the properties. You can always go back and replace a public instance attribute with a more substantial property later without breaking syntactic compatibility.

Comment: @chepner I need a setter, I am working on a parser, `_set` does other things followed by a `setattr(self, "_" + name, value)` at the end. Let me just edit the question instead

Comment: @chepner I have added `_set` method's code

Comment: @demberto you would like to use descriptors but also want doc strings for them?

Comment: I would recommend writing a custom descriptor, then adding the doc string immediately after you create an instance (as PEP-257 calls it, an attribute docstring), but I don't know if VSCode would recognize it.

Comment: @chepner Yes that could work, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless VS Code supports PEP-257's definition of attribute docstrings, this can only be considered an extended comment rather than a proper answer. I have never used VS Code and cannot test its support for this.

In its defense, it supplies the docstring syntactically, rather than setting the `__doc__` attribute dynamically at runtime, so there's a chance it will resolve the main issue raised in the question.

---

If I *weren't* concerned with IDE support, I would write a custom descriptor and follow [PEP-257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) guidelines for attribute docstrings.

```
# Adapted from examples in https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html
class IntPropety:
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.public_name = name
        self.private_name = "_" + name

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None) -> Optional[int]:
        if obj is None:
            return self
        return getattr(obj, self.private_name)

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        event = obj._events.get(self.public_name)
        if event:
            logger.info(f"Dumping value {value} to {repr(event)}")
            event.dump(value)

        setattr(obj, self.private_name, value)

    

class Child(Base):
    prop = IntProperty()
    """Doc"""
```

Comment: This is much easier

Comment: But I need to make `logger` an attribute of `self` everywhere